# Cell formatting: zero without decimal spaces and numbers with two spaces

Tags: excel, format, decimal, zero

I have a table with data like the following:

| Heat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Heat Radiated 1 | 0 |
| Heat Radiated 2 | 2554.56 |
| Heat Radiated 3 | 25.01 |
| Heat Radiated 4 | 0 |

etc...

I would like to know if it is possible to format the cells with the numbers to leave 2 decimal points on numbers different from 0, and leave the 0 alone, and of course to do so all together (not one by one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would do the following:

1. Select the range you want to modify
2. Right-click on it
3. Choose: "Format Cells"
4. In the "Number" section click "Custom"
5. In the "Type" text box type

   ## ##0,00;-# ##0,00;# ##0
6. Click OK

Read here more on how to apply custom formatting: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5

Comment: Wow! That works, thanks! Ill check the documentation from microsoft, many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=IF(<cell address>!=0, ROUND(<cell address>,2))` on all the numbers in your excel spreadsheet.

The following will only round numbers other than 0 since it is specified that `<cell address>!=0` i.e. the value in your cell should not be 0.

Note: Replace `<cell address>` with a cell address, for example `A1`.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, as I want the format to be that way, not having a formula on the cell. The user should be able to write whatever number he wants to write, with your solution the number would be in one cell, and the resulting and correctly formatted number will be in other cell, right?

Comment: @MiguelGutiérrezdeAntón No, the resulting number would be in the same cell - simply select all the cells with numbers and write the formula in the region where it says fx